# Can't get google map api to work in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the code from here to work in WordPress.  It works fine as a standalone html file.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

The link to the page I am trying is https://breastfeedchicago.org/lcpage/.

```
   <script>

      // The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
      // Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
      // to the base of the flagpole.

      function initMap() {
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: {lat: -33.9, lng: 151.2}
         });

         setMarkers(map);
      }

      // Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
      // order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
      var beaches = [
         ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
         ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
         ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
         ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
         ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
      ];

      function setMarkers(map) {
         // Adds markers to the map.

         // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
         // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

         // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
         // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
         var image = {
            url:     'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
            // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
            // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
         };
         // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
         // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
         // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
         var shape = {
            coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
            type: 'poly'
         };
         for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
            var beach = beaches[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
               map: map,
               icon: image,
               shape: shape,
               title: beach[0],
               zIndex: beach[3]
            });
         } 
      }
   </script>
   <script async defer
           src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    key=CODE&callback=initMap">
   </script>
```

Comment: don't use a `<iframe>` as map-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got that working, but I found a different tutorial that worked great with WordPress.  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/  You don't have to be using advanced custom forms to get this to work.  I was using pods.